Inverse matrix elements from exponential integral
Based on the fact that:
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\ e^{-x a} = \frac{1}{a}, \ \Re(a)>0,
$$
and that:
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\ e^{-x A} = A^{-1},
$$
if $A$ is an invertible matrix and
$$
s(A):=\sup\{\Re(\lambda):\lambda\in\sigma(A)\} >0.
$$
Is there a way to write an integral over a real parameter, a set of real parameters, a matrix, etc. such that the result is just an element of the inverse matrix?:
$$
\int_0^\infty\ ? = (A^{-1})_{ij}.
$$
More generally, given a set of matrices $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\}$, I want an integral that gives me:
$$
\to (A^{-1}_1)_{i_1,j_1}(A^{-1}_2)_{i_2,j_2}\cdots(A^{-1}_n)_{i_n,j_n}.
$$
I need to work with indices because I want the order of the products of these matrices to not be fixed, and be able to change it on a case by case basis. Is this possible?

To get just a single element, you can left and right multiply the integrand by $e_i$ and $e_j$, respectively because integration is a linear operation.

What about if I wanted to get a specific element of the chain $A^{-1}_i A^{-1}_j \cdots A^{-1}_k$? Could I simply write the exponent as $x_1 A_1 + x_2 A_2 +\cdots+ x_n A_n$ and use the same trick with $2n$ unit vectors?

That would give you the $ij$th element of the product $A_1^{-1}A_2^{-1}...$ which is not what you want.

Wouldn't this be highly dependent on how the different matrices commute with each other? In the exponent, you should be able to change the order of the sum freely, but then the order of integration would matter, right?

Yes. My statement refers to thebest case when everything commutes
